# Composer openssl cmd error

Tags: php, cmd, composer-php

When I tried to load a composer.

I get this error, I have edited **php.ini**

> From ;extension=php_openssl.dll to extension=php_openssl.dll
>   Omer58@DESKTOP-L79ED6V c:\xampp\htdocs\webshop
>
> php composer.phar install PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 Could
>   not open input file: composer.phar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reverting your php.ini and leave the dll off?
It seems the scripts load the module themselves...
I think that causes the warning.

The error of not opening composer.phar seems to be another problem. Maybe it is not in your execution path?

Comment: jo your right on the first thing i should not change that

Comment: but now i get an other error like what you said he can not find composer.phrar

Comment: never mind i did not locate right place in cmd thank you very much ;) it worked